# Why is my canvas embedded in an inline SVG not updating?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, flot

It seems like a contrived problem but I am trying to make a proof of concept of an HTML 5 document, containing inline SVG, which itself contains a <foreignObject> element with an HTML canvas inside. I then want to call a JavaScript function to draw on the canvas.

*(How I got here: I want to use SVG as a format for defining an animated graphical view which can contain graphs, which are animated by replacing a dummy element in the SVG with a live graph using JavaScript / ECMAScript, and one of the JavaScript libraries we are considering to generate the graphs (Flot) uses an HTML canvas for the view, so I want to inject this canvas into the SVG view. A further complication is we ideally want this system to run on local files, on the file:// protocol, meaning we can't run scripts on external files (e.g. referenced with <object> or <iframe>) because browsers block them, hence the inline SVG.)*

Here is an HTML source illustrating the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Canvas Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw_box() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("box_canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillRect(50, 20, 50, 60);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Canvas Test
    <p>
    <svg width="400" viewBox="-10 -10 268 108">
      <rect style="fill: #a0a0a0" x="8" y="8" width="240" height="80" rx="40" ry="40"/>
      <g>
        <rect style="fill: #0000ff" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="80" rx="40" ry="40"/>
        <rect style="fill: none; fill-opacity:0; stroke-width: 2; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke: #000000" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="80" rx="40" ry="40"/>
        <foreignObject x="120" y="25" width="150" height="100">
          <canvas id="box_canvas" width="150" height="100" style="border:1px dotted;float:left">Canvas alt text</canvas>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <p>
    <button type="button" onclick="draw_box();return false">Animate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above page doesn't display the canvas at all in IE 11. In the latest version of Chrome it displays the canvas, but the effects of the JavaScript function called by the button - drawing the black box - only show up if you click on the SVG image.

What I need to know:
1) Is there something wrong with what I've written - e.g. am I missing some function call to make the SVG or foreignObject update after I have drawn on the canvas?
2) Is this a lost cause? Is the specification of <foreignObject> etc. immature enough that I could never be confident that this will work, even if we can control what browser the user views the document in? It's actually fine if this is the case because we can just say going forward that we need our graph library to generate SVG and not HTML.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything to try and get the browser to notice, such as hiding the foreignObject (ie. `display: none`) and then showing it again?

Comment: Just to confirm that @PaulLeBeau's idea seems good. I tried it, setting the `style.display` of the _canvas_ to 'none', before drawing the box and then finally setting the `.style.display` of the canvas to '' (empty string). Works fine in latest Chrome.

Comment: Seems to work fine on Firefox. IE does not support foreignObject FWIW although I think they have plans to do so in the future.

Comment: with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/81fhj8pL/ it works fine in Chrome. In Firefox it is not rendering correctly but is updating alright. How did you test?

Comment: @RobertLongson The canvas isn't correctly aligned in the rect with rounded borders.

Comment: @RobertLongson because in chrome it is well centered in the rect with rounded borders.

Comment: @HaukeS Firefox is different to Chrome, therefore Chrome is right and Firefox is wrong? Do you have something specific as to **why** you think that?

Comment: @RobertLongson You got me there. It looked better in chrome so my assumption was that that was the correct behavior. But taking a better look into the positioning of the canvas and the foreignObject it seems to be the other way round. Firefox is showing the foreignObject where it was specified to be.

Comment: @HaukeS OK, we're on the same page, that's what I'd got.